# KeyCloak Admin Console Just Spins

Tags: keycloak, admin

Not sure if anyone can help me here, but you all have never failed in the past.  I was tasked with figuring out how to configure KeyCloak with an application my company uses.  It took me forever to figure out, but I finally have KeyCloak installed, and I'm able to hit it at https://localhost:8443.  It allowed me to set up an admin user, but when I click to go to the administration console, it just spins.  I'm running KeyCloak 19.0.1 on Windows Server 2019.  When I run the developer console in Chrome I can see:

````
{error: 'Timeout when waiting for 3rd party check iframe message.'}
error
: 
"Timeout when waiting for 3rd party check iframe message."
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
constructor
: 
ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty
: 
ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf
: 
ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable
: 
ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString
: 
ƒ toLocaleString()
toString
: 
ƒ toString()
valueOf
: 
ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__
: 
ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__
: 
ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__
: 
ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__
: 
ƒ __lookupSetter__()
__proto__
: 
(...)
get __proto__
: 
ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__
: 
ƒ __proto__()```

It doesn't help that pretty much virtually all of the troubleshooting steps I'm finding are for Linux and don't seem to make a lot of sense for what I'm looking at.  Anybody have any suggestions?
````